# Change var value in Service.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to make a mobile app. I stored "blue" as an initial value. Now I want to change the value in service.

```
.factory('repository', function() {
      var theme="button-calm";
      setTheme: function(input){
         theme=input; 
      },
      getTheme: function(){
         return theme;
     }
```

But I don't know why theme cannot be changed.

Comment: Try removing var, and see if that helps.

Comment: what is the code you use to change it?

Comment: @Aetricity, then it becomes a global variable, that's not a good solution

Comment: Alright, try printing out what theme is inside of the SetTheme function and tell results.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for your factory appears to be a bit off, make sure your factory returns a javascript object:

```
app.factory('repository', function() {
  var theme="button-calm";
  return {
    setTheme: function(input){
       theme = input; 
    },
    getTheme: function(){
       return theme;
    }
  }
});
```

next inject the factory into your controller

```
app.controller('SomeController', ['repository', function(repository) {
...
```

in your controller you can then set/get the theme:

```
repository.getTheme();
repository.setTheme('changed value');
```

see this plnkr for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/T6OoL10QzCK6hoX1HZc8?p=preview

Comment: I was about to post my answer then I saw yours. Exactly the same idea so I won't post again. But please have a look at this plunker as I put in a little bit more to demonstrate this factory: https://plnkr.co/edit/AXs6vnI7SdcB0S2KA3R3?p=preview

Comment: Thx for the answer. I did all the steps and it works. One thing is that when I want to call the function to setTheme(). I cannot do the following: repository.setTheme(color);

And color is var color, I also tried color to be $scope.color. 

So do I have to pass parameters like "value"? I cannot pass a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this service instead:

```
(function(){

service('repositoryService', function(){
    var service = {

        theme : "button-calm";

        getTheme : function(){
            return this.theme; 
        },

        setTheme : function(input){
            this.theme = input; 
        }
    };

    return service; 
});

})();
```

Obviously you will need to reference `repositoryService` in your controller, just as you needed to reference `repository`.